# Running selenium python test from soapui to read a file

Tags: python, selenium, soapui

I am running a selenium python test from soapui to read a file. When I run the code from the command line everything seems to be working fine. But when I run from the soapui it seems like it cannot find the file.

Here is my code. I believe i need to specify the full path but is there a way to just define a path so I do not have to hard copy the full path every time I call this function.

```
file_name = XMLAuto_al_log.txt
with open(file_name) as f:
            with open(outputFileName, 'w') as f1:
                for line in f:
                    if searchText in line:
                        line = line.rstrip()
                        object_id = line.split('=')[2]
                        f1.write(object_id + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
import os.path

directory = ("C:/my/directory/")
file_name = ("XMLAuto_al_log.txt")

path = os.path.join(directory + file_name)
```